# building wikipedia viewer with their API, always get error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wikipedia-api

I can't seem to get it working, I followed other code, and it didn't seem to get success, I then written it letter to letter, stil can't get success.
The url works great, I can put it in browser and it will show me the array which I need.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submitSearch").on("click", function() {
    var searchInput = $("#txtName").val();
    var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&format=json&search=" + searchInput;
    var wikiItemArray = [];
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "GET",
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error){
        console.log("There was an error somewhere in &.ajax: " + url);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The function in my code, everything looks fine, even now with dataType set to "jsonp", it's the same

Answer (score 0):

Change the `dataType` from `"json"` to `"jsonp"`.

That api is not CORS enabled but does serve jsonp

Comment: I get the same result. I'm writing the code here: https://codepen.io/daugiss/pen/EvgdVv , maybe the mistake is somewhere else